# Change windows display settings to stretched to fit external monitor using windows API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to create a program which sets the display settings into stretched mode to make display fit the physical size of the monitor the target device is running windows 7. the device by default puts the connected monitor which is good and what we want but the display is 800x600 resolution and comes as centered but we want to stretch it to make it fit on the screen, we are able to do that manually from intel graphics control center but I want to create a program that can do it automatically using windows API.

I initially printed all the members of DEVMODE structure to see the difference when I manually changed the display settings (centered and stretched) from intel driver to see what are the changes that I need to make from the windows API. I found out there was only 4 fields that changed. I'm attaching a Kdiff image of both modes centered and stretched.

Left is showing centered setting and right is showing stretched:
[image]

below is my code and `ChangeDisplaySettingsExA()` function is not returning a error. so I'm pretty much lost at this point what I'm doing wrong, if someone can guide me into right direction that will be really helpful.

```cpp
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    //Print All Montior Info (Callback function will print it)
    //cout << endl << "All connected monitors " << endl;
    //EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, EnumMonitorsProc, 0);
   
    DEVMODEA dm;
    ZeroMemory(&dm, sizeof(dm));
    dm.dmSize = sizeof(dm);
    if (0 != EnumDisplaySettingsA(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm))
    {
      

        //PrintAll(dm);

        //Changing Fields
        cout << endl <<"Fields Before Changing Values" << endl;

        cout <<"dmDisplayFrequency: " << dm.dmDisplayFrequency << endl;
        cout << "dmDisplayFixedOutput:  " << dm.dmDisplayFixedOutput << endl;
        cout << "Fields: " << dm.dmFields << endl;
        cout << "dmDeviceName: " << dm.dmDeviceName << endl;
        cout << "dmDefaultSource: " << dm.dmDefaultSource << endl;

       

        //Make it streched
        dm.dmFields = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        dm.dmDisplayFrequency = 60;
        dm.dmDisplayFixedOutput = 0;
        dm.dmDefaultSource = 0;
        dm.dmPelsWidth = 800;
        dm.dmPelsHeight = 600;
        dm.dmBitsPerPel = 32;
    
       


        LONG ret = ChangeDisplaySettingsExA(NULL, &dm, NULL, 0, NULL);
        std::cout << "ChangeDisplaySettingsEx returned " << dec << ret << '\n';
        if (0 != EnumDisplaySettingsA(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm))
        {
            cout << "DisplayFrequency after setting = " << dm.dmDisplayFrequency << endl;
        }
        switch (ret)
        {
        case DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL:
            std::cout << "display successfully changed\n";
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_BADDUALVIEW:
            std::cout << "The settings change was unsuccessful because the system is DualView capable\n";
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_BADFLAGS:
            std::cout << "An invalid set of flags was passed in.\n";
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE:
            std::cout << "The graphics mode is not supported.\n";
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM:
            std::cout << "An invalid parameter was passed in. This can include an invalid flag or combination of flags.\n";
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_FAILED:
            std::cout << "The display driver failed the specified graphics mode.\n";
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_NOTUPDATED:
            std::cout << "Unable to write settings to the registry.\n";
            break;
        case DISP_CHANGE_RESTART:
            std::cout << "The computer must be restarted for the graphics mode to work.\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    

    cout << endl << endl << endl << "Fields After Changing Values" << endl;

    cout << "dmDisplayFrequency: " << dm.dmDisplayFrequency << endl;
    cout << "dmDisplayFixedOutput:  " << dm.dmDisplayFixedOutput << endl;
    cout << "Fields: " << dm.dmFields << endl;
    cout << "dmDeviceName: " << dm.dmDeviceName << endl;
    cout << "dmDefaultSource: " << dm.dmDefaultSource << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [SetDisplayConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setdisplayconfig) function. [DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_TARGET_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-displayconfig_path_target_info) structure has a field `DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING scaling` which

> specifies how the source image is scaled to the target.

```
typedef enum  {
  DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_IDENTITY = 1,
  DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_CENTERED = 2,
  DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_STRETCHED = 3,
  DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_ASPECTRATIOCENTEREDMAX = 4,
  DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_CUSTOM = 5,
  DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_PREFERRED = 128,
  DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
} DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING;
```

> For more information about scaling, see [Scaling the Desktop Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/scaling-the-desktop-image).

2. Use [ChangeDisplaySettingsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsexa) function. See [`DUMMYUNIONNAME.DUMMYSTRUCTNAME2.dmDisplayFixedOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-devmodea).
   [image]